# How to see which JS file governing this click-to-expand content on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm looking at this [url](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/love). The original display is

[image]

After I click on the plus sign,

[image]

I see that `<section>` changes to `<section expand>`, and `aria-expanded="false"` changes to `aria-expanded="true"`. Could you please elaborate on how to determine which JS file governs this behavior?

I can see many JS files in section "Event Listeners" but could not figure out?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the page. From your screenshot you can see there is only one of the event listeners on "click" that applies to that specific header element - amp-accordion.js.

This name makes sense as it is an accordion effect you're looking at.

Inside the .js file referenced there are a number of sections governing the accordion effect. If you'd like to investigate further I recommend searching for the term "accordion" in the js source - CTRL+F, "accordion".