# Toggle visibility of the current element

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm trying to write a function `toggle_active` to show the hidden content on a click, and collapse the content again on one more click. Sadly, it does not work. Could you help me modify it?

```js
function toggle_active(this){
  var x = this.nextSibling;
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  };
}
```

```css
.daccord_b{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<header class="ca_h" onclick="toggle_active(this);">
    <i class="i i-plus ca_hi"></i>
    Title
</header>
<div class="had daccord_b">Hidden content</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use method `nextElementSibling` to return the next element. And it is not necessary to use the `if {}` operator.

Don't use `this` for arguments in functions.

The more correct way for your task is method `toggle()`, which your class uses in css `.daccord_b`.

```js
function toggle_active(el) {
    var x = el.nextElementSibling;
    x.classList.toggle("daccord_b");
}
```

```css
.daccord_b {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="ca_h" onclick="toggle_active(this);">
    <i class="i i-plus ca_hi"></i>
    Title
</header>
<div class="had daccord_b">Hidden content</div>
```

Second solution using `style.display`.

```js
function toggle_active(el) {
    var x = el.nextElementSibling;
    x.style.display = x.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

```css
.daccord_b {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="ca_h" onclick="toggle_active(this);">
    <i class="i i-plus ca_hi"></i>
    Title
</header>
<div class="had daccord_b">Hidden content</div>
```

Comment: I would like to ask if I can specify the property of `daccord_b` to toggle. For example, `display`. This is for the case `daccord_b` has many properties and we want to change just one of them.

Comment: @LEAnhDung, Do you mean using `style.display`?

Comment: Yesss. In my project, your function with `classList.toggle` works well, only except for a small issue, i.e, the paragraph is un-indented. On the other hand, my original function (after modified with `nextElementSibling`) keeps the original indentation. But one issue with my function is that: the first click does not change anything. The effect only happens from the second click. Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: @LEAnhDung, I am familiar with this problem. The effect occurs only after the second click, because after the first click your element receives a `display: none` (for example). This is because the style attribute takes precedence over the ccc rules, and an overlap is obtained.

Comment: I thought I already set `display: none;` in CSS?

Comment: @LEAnhDung, I made you a second solution using `style.display`. Check, pls.

Comment: Your second one works like a charm. Do you have any idea why `x.classList.toggle("daccord_b")` in your first method changes the indentation of the element?

Comment: @LEAnhDung, It's hard for me to guess because I can't see all the code. Oddly enough, the first solution should also work without side effects, because the `div` tag has a default `display: block`.

Comment: Thank you so much @ s.kuznetsov for your dedicated help!. In my html, the default of `daccord_b` is `display: none`.

Comment: If you have time, I hope that you can have a look at my related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514329/how-to-see-which-js-file-governing-this-click-to-expand-content-on-a-website). This is where all problems arise.

Answer (score 1):

You're having some syntax errors in this code. First, I suggest you name the function arguments something other than `this` because `this` is a reserved **keyword** in JavaScript.

Secondly, I recommend consulting with W3School with such simple problems before reaching out, as most of the time, there is a simple solution :)

Here's a link that solves exactly the problem you're describing.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp

And, here's an example and how you can achieve this:

```js
let content = document.getElementById("content");

function handleClick() {
  if (content.classList.contains("hide")) {
     content.classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
     content.classList.add("hide");
  }
}
```

```css
.my-content {
  display: block;
}

.my-content.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="handleClick()">Toggle</button>

<div class="my-content" id="content">Hello, some content</div>
```

**EDIT** If you decide to introduce jQuery to your project, you can achieve it even with fever lines of code:

```js
$("[data-collapse]").on('click', function () {
   let target = $(this).data('collapse');
   $(target).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-collapse="#content">Clicker</button>


<div id="content">
My Content
</div>
```

This makes it **abstract** and reusable, even allowing you to do things like separate containers:

```js
$("[data-collapse]").on('click', function () {
   let target = $(this).data('collapse');
   $(target).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button data-collapse="#target1">Collapse #1</button>
<button data-collapse="#target2">Collapse #2</button>


<div id="target1">
  <h1>I'm Target #1</h1>
</div>

<div id="target2">
  <h1>I'm target #2</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
js:

function toggle_active(id){
      var x = document.getElementById(id);
      if (x.style.display === "none" || x.style.display === "") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      };
    }
```

html:

```
    <header class="ca_h" onclick="toggle_active('HiddenContent');">
   toggle
</header>
<div class="had daccord_b" id='HiddenContent'>Hidden content</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to use an Event object in you handler function when you can. Please read this post then try fixing your code accordingly: [What exactly is the parameter e (event) and why pass it to JavaScript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936365/what-exactly-is-the-parameter-e-event-and-why-pass-it-to-javascript-functions)

More about `Event.currentTarget` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

```js
function toggle_active(evt){
  var x = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
  x.classList.toggle('daccord_b'); 
}
```

```css
.daccord_b {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="ca_h" onclick="toggle_active(event);">
    <i class="i i-plus ca_hi"></i>
    Title
</header>
<div class="had daccord_b">Hidden content</div>
```